# How to sum same columns present in multiple tables and show there result as one

Tags: mysql, sum

I have more than 4 tables with same columns, All I just want is to sum the columns and display the result as one for each column. My table is:

Table 1

```
-----------------------------------------------
| amount  |    tax1.  |    tax2.  |    gtotal |
----------------------------------------------

Table2 

-----------------------------------------------
| amount  |    tax1.  |    tax2.  |    gtotal |
----------------------------------------------

Table3. 

 -----------------------------------------------
| amount  |    tax1.  |    tax2.  |    gtotal |
----------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM All_Tables

SELECT SUM(tax1) FROM All_Tables

SELECT SUM(tax2) FROM All_Tables

SELECT SUM(gtotal) FROM All_Tables
```

and `SUM` function also have where clause.

Comment: Why have multiple tables?

Comment: user 1, user 2 , i mean multiple billing user database

Comment: Eh? You have a separate table for each user?

Comment: multiple billing users, each  user had its. own data to be saved in its table, and for reports i have to sum all the columns in the end.

Comment: share 3 tables sample data and your expected output because your information says you have more things in your table that you not shared yet

Comment: @BRUCEWAYNE is there any joining key among those 3 tables

Comment: i tried to share an image but 10 reputation points message appeared

Comment: @BRUCEWAYNE why you will share image? just write those things in text or write in google docs and give your  docs link here in your problem

Comment: @zaynul Abadin Tuhin already written in text, see my question again with details.

Comment: @BRUCEWAYNE provide valid sample data in each table

Comment: Seriously consider amending your data model

Comment: try to Answer queries , and not to change the data models, like seriously.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(tax1), SUM(tax2), SUM(gtotal) 
FROM (
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(tax1), SUM(tax2), SUM(gtotal) FROM Table1
UNION ALL SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(tax1), SUM(tax2), SUM(gtotal) FROM Table2) a
```

Answer (score 0):

[Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(tax1), SUM(tax2), SUM(amount + tax1 + tax2)
FROM(
            SELECT amount, tax1, tax2, gtotal FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL SELECT amount, tax1, tax2, gtotal FROM Table2
  UNION ALL SELECT amount, tax1, tax2, gtotal FROM Table3
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `UNION ALL` since OP wants to sum all the rows, not distinct ones?

Comment: and i want to sum(amount+ tax1+tax2) instead the of sum(gtotal)

Comment: Updated it. That works exactly as you have written: SUM(amount + tax1 + tax2)